# Load a specified site when visited from certain domain

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm not sure what to search for, but this is what I want to achieve.

I have a domain name registered somewhere. I also have a dedicated Linux server somewhere else. I'm running a website (Apache/PHP) on that Linux server that I can now visit through:

`http://[my server ip address]/subfolder-1/index.php`

I changed the DNS settings of my domain name to the IP address of my Linux server. Right now when I goto my domain name it actually loads the `index.php` at: `http://[my server ip address]`.

I know I can do something in Aapache so that it knows when a user comes from `www.mydomain.com`, that it should display the site located in:

`http://[my server ip address]/subfolder-1/index.php`

And when I come from `www.my-otherdomain.com` that it should load the site from:

`http://[my server ip address]/subfolder-2/index.php`

But I'm not sure what to look for and how this is called? How can I configure my Apache server for that?

Comment: You are looking for virtual hosts. And the paths can be anywhere on the server, they are not limited to sub-directories of your main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup virtual hosts for each domains on Apache like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

after that reload the server :

> sudo service apache2 restart